# RewriteRule to remove extraneous URL parts for pretty URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pretty-urls

### Background

Trying to recreate StackOverflow-style pretty URLs using Apache's mod rewrite and PHP.

### Problem

This works great:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteRule ([0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

URLs like `http://localhost/home/script/5` redirect to `http://localhost/home/script/index.php?r=5`. The CSS content loads flawlessly.

URLs like `http://24.68.226.186/recipes/recipe/5/seo-text` redirect, but the relative path for the CSS files is then incorrect:

```
<link rel="StyleSheet" hreF="css/theme.css" type="text/css" media="screen,print" id="css-theme" />
```

### Directories

The directory structure for the script (index.php) resembles:

```
htdocs/home/script
htdocs/home/script/.htaccess
htdocs/home/script/index.php
htdocs/home/script/css
htdocs/home/script/images
```

### Question

How do you use mod rewrite to tell Apache to use the "script" directory when serving files instead of any sub-directory appended to the URL?

In other words, how would you use mod rewrite to lop off the "seo-text" part of the URL and (1) ensure it reflects the actual title [sourced from a database]; (2) redirect the browser to the new URL [if necessary]; and (3) tell Apache to ignore all paths beyond the ID in the URL?

I would rather not use absolute paths in the CSS.

Thank you!

Comment: Would using the `base` HTML tag (even if updated dynamically) be an option? (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)

Comment: Can't you set your stylesheet direct to use the root directory by adding a forward slash like this `/css/theme.css` ?

Comment: The development environment has a different root than the production environment. In development it is `/home/account/htdocs/site/root` and in production it is `/home/account/site/htdocs/root`, which is why absolute paths won't work (without some effort that I'd rather avoid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Logan's advice:

```
<base href="/home/script/" target="_self" />
```

This does not work with IE8, due to a bug.